# Opensubtitles new REST API returns 401 unauthorized

Tags: rest, curl, http-post

I'm trying to get an auth-token to use the REST API from opensubtitles but when I send a request I recieve a 401 unauthorized

This is my curl request that I copied off their docs

```sh
curl -X POST "https://www.opensubtitles.com/api/v1/login" -d '{
  "username": "username",
  "password": "password"
}' \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

This is the response I got

```json
{"message":"Error, Unauthorized","status":401}
```

At first, I thought it was a password error so I tried changing my password to login but it was still not working. Then I even tried to use my email as my username but it still didn't work.

I even tried to make a new account and login but I kept on recieving the same response.

Comment: It looks like REST API requests should be submitted to a different domain, https://rest.opensubtitles.org (as per https://forum.opensubtitles.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=16453#p39771). Additionally, the authentication endpoint appears to be https://rest.opensubtitles.org/auth.

Comment: Hey I figured it out, apparently opensubtitles.COM and opensubtitles.ORG have different databases with their accounts so my account on .org does not exists on .com. I went ahead and made an account on .com and its working fine now. Your method also works but thats requesting from .org